# Old site migration options

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp-classic, migration

My client has an old web site which was written in Classic ASP, with MySQL database (MyISAM). It's has been written by developers with different levels of experience over the last 10 years. Some aspects of the system are a mess.

It has no CMS, has a shopping basket, and a quite complicated My Account and Admin areas.
Some of the (simpler) areas of the website have been converted to ASP.NET (uses MySQL .NET Connector).

Rewriting the system from scratch will never be approved by the client who has a limited budget. But can gradually get it into a form that's easier to maintain.

The plan is:

1. Install a 3rd party o/s CMS (like Umbraco), migrate the content pages, integrate custom user authentication and link My Account and Admin areas.
2. Upgrade database so that foreign keys are supported.
3. Upgrade Classic ASP site and ASP.NET components to support the above changes
4. Keep changes to Classic ASP site to a minimum and write new stuff in ASP.NET

**So the questions are:**

1. Is it a reasonable plan? Or is it going to bite us later?
2. What database system to use? `MS SQL or MySQL Inno DB?`

   - *I personally prefer MS SQL. Luckily, the Classic ASP stuff has been written with a db manager class that handles all communication, which will make it relatively easy to upgrade to MS SQL. But is it worth the effort?*

Answer (score 2):

I think you just described the perfect client to run away from. You've got a site that has been cobbled together with duct tape and bailing wire and you want to add some tie downs and a coat of paint. You might get it to work but it will never be right and you will never get paid for the amount of work that needs to be done.

A variation of an old adage applies here - if you can't afford to do it right the first time, how will you afford to do it again. Your client needs to save up so they can budget the proper amount to do this project right the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little too low on details to give a full recommendation on (I also suspect you've already handled this situation since it's an old question but nevertheless...).

If your client truly is not able to afford a replacement solution then I think your upgrade plan is the best out of the bad options. But I have the following reservations:

- Step 1 may be workable if the level of integration between content pages and the shop is low. Otherwise you may run into problems. I notice you already thought about user authentication. Anything else like this?
- I believe step 3-4 are probably not workable in practice, solely on my experience with badly designed software. Small changes usually cause a chain-reaction and you will not easily be able to isolate them. Your chances of success rest with being able to divide and conquer - by which I mean leave the old parts intact (aside from emergency fixes). Externalize solutions if you can.
- Referring the above, it may be costly to replace the underlying database. Depending on complexity of data and queries, there can be a lot of hidden surprises here.
- This is based on your statement about a limited budget. Trying to retrofit something like this over time is somewhat doubtful that it will be cheaper than a full replacement. It really depends on the size of the client...if it is a big site, then a full rewrite of a complex piece of software will take too long. If it is a small project, perhaps a few months for a small team, then I think it will be cheaper to do it all at once.

Anyway, this has been my experience when doing these things previously. Your mileage may of course vary.